# cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'DISTINCT' '(' in expression specification -Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Trying to execute below query in hive. throwing exception cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'DISTINCT' '(' in expression specification. any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (FISCAL_QUARTER_START_DATE)
      FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE
     WHERE     FISCAL_YEAR_ID =
                  (SELECT FISCAL_YEAR_ID
                     FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE
                    WHERE CALENDAR_DATE = FROM_UNIXTIME (UNIX_TIMESTAMP ()))
           AND SUBSTR (FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2) =
                  (SELECT SUBSTR (FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2)
                     FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE
                    WHERE CALENDAR_DATE = FROM_UNIXTIME (UNIX_TIMESTAMP ()))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use proper table aliases and `IN` clause instead of `=` for sub-queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t1.FISCAL_QUARTER_START_DATE)
FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE t1
WHERE t1.FISCAL_YEAR_ID IN (
        SELECT t2.FISCAL_YEAR_ID
        FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE t2
        WHERE t2.CALENDAR_DATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
        )
    AND SUBSTR(t1.FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2) IN (
        SELECT SUBSTR(t3.FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2)
        FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE t3
        WHERE t3.CALENDAR_DATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
        );
```

I think your query is equivalent and could be converted to a single sub-query with `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FISCAL_QUARTER_START_DATE
FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE t1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM TEST_STAGE.TEST_TABLE t2
        WHERE SUBSTR(t1.FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2) = SUBSTR(t2.FISCAL_QUARTER_NAME, 0, 2)
            AND t1.FISCAL_YEAR_ID = t2.FISCAL_YEAR_ID
            AND t1.CALENDAR_DATE = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
        );
```